# Convert one date format to other date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have date in the format:

```
AUG FY2014 (there is space between AUG and FY2014)
```

I need to compare it with another date which has different format:

```
201408
```

How to convert the first one to the same format as second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where left(convert(varchar,cast('01 '+replace('AUG FY2014','FY','') as datetime),112),6)='201408'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert both strings to `DATETIME` value. The second datetime can be convert to `yyyymmdd` by adding `01` and can be handled by `expression_style=112` of the CONVERT function, see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for more details

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'201408'+'01',112)
```

The first date requires some parsing as `FY` is not valid in a date string. After removing this string, you can convert your date to `dd mon yyyy` that can be handled by `expression_style=106`.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('1 ' + 'AUG FY2014', 'FY', ''),106)
```

Comment: when into second query insted of '201408' put column name, I got error:

     CONVERT(DATETIME,[Col1]+'01',112)

Comment: If Rajesh answer works, you need to use `LEFT([columnname],6)`

Comment: CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([col1],6) +'01',112) -> still wrong